# Python: Repeating a function until a keypress is initiated

Tags: python, psychopy

My function 'hello()' simply displays a stimulus on screen for 2 seconds, during which time a key can be pressed. If a key isn't pressed, it waits 1 second and then runs the function again, over and over if no keys are pressed. When a key is pressed it exits the while loop and prints yes. For some reason, if I let the function loop over, for example, 4 times before i press a key, I then get 5 print staments out at the same time, whereas I would only expect one. Can someone tell me why it seems to be storing print statements, despite that I would expect the print statement never to be reached until I pressed a key?

```
def hello():
    test = 1 
    running = 1
    while running == 1:
        for frame in range(short_frames):      # 2 seconds
            fix.draw()
            window.flip()

            allKeys = event.getKeys(keyList = ('g','h'))
            for thisKey in allKeys:
                if thisKey == 'g':
                    keyTime=core.getTime()
                    test = 2
                elif thisKey == 'h':
                    keyTime=core.getTime()
                    test = 2

        window.flip()
        core.wait(1)

        if test == 1:               #if no key is pressed
            hello()                 #run the function again

        running = 2                 #exit out of while loop

    print "yes"

for i in range(1):
    hello()
core.quit()
window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have called the function `hello` in `hello`. It's **recursion**. By the 5.th time, you press a key. It will print your *`thing`* and end the 5.th call of `hello`. Your program returns to the 4.th `hello` and catches the pressed key. The 4.th call of your function `hello` will print again, end your 4.th `hello` and return to the 3.th call of `hello` and so so so.....

You should careful with **`recursion`**. 
I don't know, why you need the variables `test` and `running`. But this codes will work.

```
def hello():
    is_pressed = False
    while not is_pressed:
        for frame in range(short_frames):      # 2 seconds
            fix.draw()
            window.flip()

            allKeys = event.getKeys(keyList = ('g','h'))
            for thisKey in allKeys:
                if thisKey == in ['g', 'h']
                    keyTime=core.getTime()
                    is_pressed = True

        window.flip()
        core.wait(1)

    print "yes"
```

Comment: Thanks. Whilst this keeps the while loop going until a key is pressed, I need the whole function to be run again if no key is pressed, not just the while loop. This is why I was calling hello() again from within hello(), I thought it would instantly jump back to the start of the function without printing.

Comment: While I agree with all the warnings against recursion, and I think you can do what you want more simply, it is possible to test for the absence of a key press with something like: `keys = event.waitKeys(maxWait = 1800, keyList = keyList); if isinstance(keys, types.NoneType) or keys[0] == 'escape': quit();` where the `NoneType` is used for these lines to see whether to quit a part of one of our programs.

Answer (score 0):

hello() is calling itself recursively. It's going to print the output once for every time it's called. To get the effect you want, you need something like this:

```
def hello():
    test = 1 
    running = 1
    while running == 1:
        for frame in range(short_frames):      # 2 seconds
            fix.draw()
            window.flip()

            allKeys = event.getKeys(keyList = ('g','h'))
            for thisKey in allKeys:
                if thisKey == 'g':
                    keyTime=core.getTime()
                    test = 2
                elif thisKey == 'h':
                    keyTime=core.getTime()
                    test = 2

        window.flip()
        core.wait(1)
        running = test

    print "yes"

for i in range(1):
    hello()
core.quit()
window.close()
```

At the bottom of the while loop, if test has not changed (i.e., a key was not pressed), running will be set to 1 and the loop will continue. If test is 2 (a key was pressed), running will be set to 2 and the loop will exit. The "yes" string will only be printed once because hello() is only called once.

UPDATE:

```
def hello():
    test = 1 
    for frame in range(short_frames):      # 2 seconds
        fix.draw()
        window.flip()

        allKeys = event.getKeys(keyList = ('g','h'))
        for thisKey in allKeys:
            if thisKey == 'g':
                keyTime=core.getTime()
                test = 2
            elif thisKey == 'h':
                keyTime=core.getTime()
                test = 2

        window.flip()
        core.wait(1)
        return test

running = 1
while running == 1:
    running = hello()
print "yes"
core.quit()
window.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. Whilst this keeps the while loop going until a key is pressed, I need the whole function to be run again if no key is pressed, not just the while loop. This is why I was calling hello() again from within hello(), I thought it would instantly jump back to the start of the function without printing.

Comment: See the update in my answer. It's easy enough to move the while loop outside the function so that the function gets called on every iteration. If you care about being "pythonic", it would be more so to use True and False for the condition values in test and running (as opposed to 1 and 2).